# How to convert Spannable to AnnotatedString in Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a large project that uses regular android layouts. I'm starting to use compose on this project. However, I already have a large codebase and a lot of utils that deal with CharSequence and Spannable. For example, currency formatter that returns Spannable.

Compose `Text` doesn't accept neither CharSequence nor Spannable. However, it does accept `AnnotatedString` and, from what I can tell, they are basically the same thing. So I'm thinking that there must be a way to easily convert `Spannable` to `AnnotatedString`, something like `spannable.toAnnotatedString()`, but I can't find anything so far.

Can I convert `Spannable` to `AnnotatedString` or do I have to write a lot of code from scratch?

Comment: Sorry could you help me understand how you turned your String resource into a spannable in kotlin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution works for basic html, but you might want to add more Copier classes to support more exotic spans.

```
fun Spannable.toAnnotatedString(primaryColor: Color): AnnotatedString {
    val builder = AnnotatedString.Builder(this.toString())
    val copierContext = CopierContext(primaryColor)
    SpanCopier.values().forEach { copier ->
        getSpans(0, length, copier.spanClass).forEach { span ->
            copier.copySpan(span, getSpanStart(span), getSpanEnd(span), builder, copierContext)
        }
    }
    return builder.toAnnotatedString()
}

private data class CopierContext(
    val primaryColor: Color,
)

private enum class SpanCopier {
    URL {
        override val spanClass = URLSpan::class.java
        override fun copySpan(
            span: Any,
            start: Int,
            end: Int,
            destination: AnnotatedString.Builder,
            context: CopierContext
        ) {
            val urlSpan = span as URLSpan
            destination.addStringAnnotation(
                tag = name,
                annotation = urlSpan.url,
                start = start,
                end = end,
            )
            destination.addStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(color = context.primaryColor, textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline),
                start = start,
                end = end,
            )
        }
    },
    FOREGROUND_COLOR {
        override val spanClass = ForegroundColorSpan::class.java
        override fun copySpan(
            span: Any,
            start: Int,
            end: Int,
            destination: AnnotatedString.Builder,
            context: CopierContext
        ) {
            val colorSpan = span as ForegroundColorSpan
            destination.addStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(color = Color(colorSpan.foregroundColor)),
                start = start,
                end = end,
            )
        }
    },
    UNDERLINE {
        override val spanClass = UnderlineSpan::class.java
        override fun copySpan(
            span: Any,
            start: Int,
            end: Int,
            destination: AnnotatedString.Builder,
            context: CopierContext
        ) {
            destination.addStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline),
                start = start,
                end = end,
            )
        }
    },
    STYLE {
        override val spanClass = StyleSpan::class.java
        override fun copySpan(
            span: Any,
            start: Int,
            end: Int,
            destination: AnnotatedString.Builder,
            context: CopierContext
        ) {
            val styleSpan = span as StyleSpan

            destination.addStyle(
                style = when (styleSpan.style) {
                    Typeface.ITALIC -> SpanStyle(fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic)
                    Typeface.BOLD -> SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                    Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC -> SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic)
                    else -> SpanStyle()
                },
                start = start,
                end = end,
            )
        }
    };

    abstract val spanClass: Class<out CharacterStyle>
    abstract fun copySpan(span: Any, start: Int, end: Int, destination: AnnotatedString.Builder, context: CopierContext)
}
```

Comment: Good and helpful to start with. I just rewrote the converter to work on all source spans, find/invoke converter, and report error if no converter was found.  
getSpans(0, length, Any::class.java).forEach { sp ->
        SpanCopier.values().firstOrNull { sc -> sc.spanClass.isInstance(sp) }
            ?.copySpan(sp, getSpanStart(sp), getSpanEnd(sp), b)
            ?: App.warn("Unknown span: ${sp.javaClass.simpleName}")
    }