# Emphasizing parts of a string resource in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to render a `<string />` resource containing “Finished *x* out of *y* tasks.” with an emphasis (e.g. bold) on the *x* and the *y* in Jetpack Compose?

Without a string resource, I could build an annotated string using the `buildAnnotatedString` DSL:

```kotlin
val x = "2"
val y = "10"

val string = buildAnnotatedString {
  append("Finished ")
  withStyle(emphasized) { append(x) }
  append(" out of ")
  withStyle(emphasized) { append(y) }
  append(" tasks.")
}

Text(string)
```

But this gets more complicated when using a string resource.

```xml
<string name="txt">Finished %1$d out of %2$d</string>
```

```kotlin
buildAnnotatedString {
  append(stringResource(R.string.txt, 2, 10))

  // How do I properly apply the correct styles
  // in the places of the “2” and “10”?
}
```

Doing something like

1. `val xPosition = string.indexOf("2")`,
2. `addStyle(bold, xPosition, xPosition + "2".count())`,
3. `val yPosition = string.indexOf("10")`, and
4. `addStyle(bold, yPosition, yPosition + "10".count())`

feels wrong. What if the numbers are the same (“10 out of 10”)?

One could split up the string into multiple resources:

```xml
<string name="txt_pt1">Finished </string>
<string name="txt_pt2"> out of </string>
<string name="txt_pt3"> tasks.</string>
```

```kotlin
buildAnnotatedString {
  append(stringResource(R.string.txt_pt1))
  withStyle(emphasized) { append("2") }
  append(stringResource(R.string.txt_pt2))
  withStyle(emphasized) { append("10") }
  append(stringResource(R.string.txt_pt3))
}
```

But this, too, feels wrong, and could also negatively impact translations. What if, in one language, it would make more sense to move the numbers around (“out of 10 tasks, 2 are finished”)?

Comment: You could put HTML-style tags in the string resource (`<string name="txt">Finished <i>%1$d</i> out of <i>%2$d</i></string>`) and use `getText()` on `Resources` to retrieve it. That will give you a `Spanned` with the formatting. Then, you can [convert the `Spanned` to an `AnnotatedString`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73989319/115145).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But while this would probably allow me to just emphasize the text, as I asked for, I don't see how it could allow me to apply any kind of style from our design system. Since emphasizing in our case means to apply a specific `TextStyle`, I'm afraid that wouldn't be enough.

Comment: "I don't see how it could allow me to apply any kind of style from our design system" -- well, how you map `<b>` and `<i>` to your design system is up to you. If you need more options than that, use `<annotation>`: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/styling-internationalized-text-in-android-f99759fb7b8f and https://gist.github.com/florina-muntenescu/08d751d843d55b75061039fee4e97931

Comment: The `<annotation />`s seem like exactly what I want, actually! Although the conversion from `Spanned` to `AnnotatedString` is cumbersome, but there's the link you posted above. Thanks again, I'll give this a shot! :)

Comment: @Commonsware I havnt figured out how to use getText to retrieve a Spannable from string.xml could you maybe expand on that or turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @quealegriamasalegre: [`getText()` will return a `CharSequence`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources?hl=en#getText(int)), and IIRC it should be [an implementation of `Spanned`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned), not `Spannable`.